# Should I delete separable programs after `glUseProgramStages`?

Tags: opengl

If I create a bunch of separable program objects and put them into program pipelines, should I call `glDeleteProgram` immediately or do they have to outlive their pipelines?

https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Compilation#Separate_programs says that pipeline objects are container objects, and https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Object#Deletion_orphaning says that objects attached to a container are in use and not deleted.

For comparison, I see plenty of examples that call `glDeleteShader` on shaders once they're linked into a program (e.g. https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Compilation#Cleanup specifically recommends this).

I've experimented with deleting programs out from under their pipeline and nothing seems to be harmed, but of course I'm not relying on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason shader objects are often deleted after linking them into program objects is that shader objects they are *independent* of programs. The linked program contains all of the code from the shader objects that it linked together. You can detach those shaders from the programs, and that will have zero effect on the successfully linked program object.

That is *not* the case for pipeline objects. Pipelines simply contain the separate programs to be used for rendering. They don't absorb the information from them. Now yes, they do preserve the lifetime of the attached objects, but they don't exist independently of those objects.

Detach those objects, and the pipeline will have no code to execute for a stage.

Also, if you delete the program, how would you change its uniforms? You can't even use `glActiveShaderProgram`, since you would need to actually have the program object. Sure, you can use `glGetProgramPipelineiv` to fetch the (now deleted) program name for a particular stage, but why do that? `glGet` calls are not known for performance.

So, can you do this? Yes. Is it a good idea? No.

Lastly, since people commonly don't do this, reliance on such deletion orphaning and querying of deleted object names is dangerous. It opens you up to lots of driver bugs. There have been cases of OpenGL implementations returning orphaned names from new `glGen` calls.

Answer (score 0):

> If program is not current for any GL context, is not the active program for any program pipeline object, and is not the current program for any stage of any program pipeline object, it is deleted immediately. Otherwise, program is flagged for deletion and will be deleted after all of these conditions become true.

[The OpenGL® Graphics System, Version 4.1, Core Profile](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec41.core.pdf#page=77), July 25, 2010, p. 60. - §2.11.3 Shader Objects.

Yes you can, based on the specification and if the described behavior suits you. Good choice not to do this because of possible bugs in the driver implementation, e.g. on my PC the `program` is deleted despite the fact that it is active for the current context.

Comment: "*is not the current program for any stage of any program pipeline object*" Which means if it *is* the current program for a pipeline stage, it *won't* be deleted yet. So the answer would be... yes. Right?

Comment: Right, your answer is more complete. Although "No" is the correct answer to this question, it lacks the details. Thank you.

Comment: But it's not correct. Your answer suggests that you *cannot*, then quotes from the specification as if that were proof. Even though the very quote is saying that you *can*. My answer is that you can, but you *shouldn't*.